# Can i scan the files like normal folder in amazon s3 with django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I have the Django app and i am thinking of using the Amazon S3 for storing 20GB of pdf files.

Now i won't be directly serving them but i am thinking of like this. please give me right direction if something is wrong

1. Django will scan the all files from S3 and will populate the database tables of all filenames , sizes etc.
2. Then i will show the list of them om web page so that i can track the how many times the file is downloaded
3. Then i will serve the file from amazon S3

Is this kind of thing possible

My Django app is using apache , mod_wsgi  and VPS server Centos 6

Comment: The storage backend you use is essentially transparent so anything you can do on your local VPS you can do on S3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible (and is in fact a good way to go). You can use the [boto library](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to [scan your directory on S3](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html#accessing-a-bucket) to store it in your database. With this information you can [generate download links](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.generate_url) for the files. It is also possible to automatically let the download links from S3 expire after a certain amount of time.

Comment: thanks man , i will look into it. Does it also  scans folders as well. i mean what i am thinking is first make the folder as i like in hard drive and then upload it.

Comment: There is no such thing as folders in S3, every object is stored as a single key. And if the key contains a "/" character, the clients may decide to show it as a folder.